# I want to joint multiple ID'S in my SQL table

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have a table when my database Users and which one has an ID, and i want to say like ID 1 and 2 belong to the same Project, i cannot do that, what i can do i say that ID 1 bellong to this project but i really need to add multiple ID'S to the project, if anyone could help me please.

Comment: Create a table `projectUsers(ProjectId, UserId)`